# prediction and decision making with neural netwok

Tags: neural-network, correlation, prediction

i am new in neural network and i have a basic question to make sure what i have in mind about the neural network application is not wrong. 
lets say  i have two sets of data in my project.the first set of data is given to me and the second set of data was calculated later. I want to find relationship and correlation between these two sets of data and then predict the second set of data for any different first set of data. is neural network what I need ? if yes, how can i start doing this ? any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Neural network to do this. I have implemented a neural network for similar purpose please see the sample code at https://github.com/naveenkambham/MachineLearningModels/blob/master/NeuralNetwork.py. In the sample X is first Set and Y is second set.
If you find this helpful mark this as answer. Lemme know if you got any questions.